# Merge [washing-machine] and [clothes-washer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [washing-machine](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/washing-machine) be a synonym of [clothes-washer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes-washer)?

Relative term usage info is [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=washing%20machine%2Cclothes%20washer%2C%20washer&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwashing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwashing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWashing%20Machine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWashing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWASHING%20MACHINE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cclothes%20washer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bclothes%20washer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClothes%20washer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClothes%20Washer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCLOTHES%20WASHER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwasher%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwasher%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWasher%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWASHER%3B%2Cc0), which does not clearly answer the directionality question.
My proposal is that "clothes-washer" is less ambiguous especially for non-native speakers of English; a [dishwasher](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishwasher) is also technically a washing machine (i.e. machine that washes) if you consider the terms individually.

Answer (score 7):

I agree these should be synonyms. Washing machine is certainly the term most used in the US, hence the many more questions tagged with that. Typically that would mean clothes washer would be the synonym, though you make a good point that non-native speakers may be confused by this. I've updated the tag wiki to hopefully remove the confusion and approved the proposed synonym for [clothes-washer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes-washer) to become [washing-machine](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/washing-machine) which should be the more popular term.